# Identities of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $U$ a set and $A,B$ subsets of $U$.

I have to prove the following sentences:

1. $A \cap A^c=\varnothing, \ \ \ \ A \cup A^c=U$
2. $(A^c)^c=A$
3. $(A \cap B)^c=A^c \cup B^c$
4. $(A \cup B)^c=A^c \cap B^c$
5. $A \setminus B=A \cap B^c$

That's what I have tried:

1. - $x \in A \cap A^c \leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge x \in A^c \leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge x \in U \setminus A \leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge(x \in U \wedge x \notin A) $, that is a contradiction. So, there is no $x$, such that $x \in A \cap A^c$, so we conclude that $A \cap A^c=\varnothing$.
   - $x \in A \cup A^c \leftrightarrow x \in A \lor x \in A^c \leftrightarrow x \in A \lor x \in U \setminus A \leftrightarrow x \in A \lor (x \in U \wedge x \notin A) \leftrightarrow x \in U$. Therefore, $A \cup A^c=U$
2. $x \in (A^c)^c \leftrightarrow x \in U \setminus A^c \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \notin A^c \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \in  A \leftrightarrow x \in A$

So, we conclude that $(A^c)^c=A$.

3. $x \in (A \cap B)^c \leftrightarrow x \in U \setminus A \cap B \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \notin A \cap B$
   How can we continue?

**EDIT**:

Could we prove maybe the sentences $4,5$ like that?

4. $$x \in (A \cup B)^c \leftrightarrow x \in U \setminus (A \cup B) \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \notin A \cup B \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \notin A \wedge x \notin B \\ \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \in A^c \wedge x \in B^c \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \in A^c \cap B^c \leftrightarrow x \in A^c \cap B^c$$
5. $$x \in A \setminus B \leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge x \notin B \leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge x \in B^c \leftrightarrow x \in A \cap B^c$$

Comment: Generally you should ask one question at a time.  You can finish your third part via $x\notin A\cap B\leftrightarrow (x\notin A)\vee (x\notin B)\leftrightarrow (x\in A^c)\vee (x\in B^c)\leftrightarrow x\in (A^c \cup B^c)$.

Comment: So, could we prove the third sentence like that?

$$x \in (A \cap B)^c \leftrightarrow x \in U \setminus A \cap B \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \notin A \cap B \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge ((x \notin A) \lor (x \notin B)) \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge ((x \in A^c) \lor (x \in B^c)) \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge (x \in A^c \cup B^c) \leftrightarrow x \in A^c \cup B^c$$

Answer (score 1):

Just some hints:

3) If $x$ is not in the intersection of $A$ and $B$, then $x\notin A$ **or** $x\notin B$. So $x\in A^c$ **or** $x\in B^c$.

4) You want to show containment both ways. Say that $x\in (A\cup B)^c$. Then $x\notin A$ and $x\notin B$. So $x$ is in their intersection. This proves $(A\cup B)^c \subseteq A^c\cap B^c$. Now do the other way ...

5) Again let $x\in A\setminus B$. So $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$. So $x\in A\cap B^c$. The other way I leave to you.

Remember that if an element $x$ is in two sets $A$ and $B$, then $x\in A\cap B$.

Comment: So, could we prove the third sentence like that?

$$x \in (A \cap B)^c \leftrightarrow x \in U \setminus A \cap B \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \notin A \cap B \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge ((x \notin A) \lor (x \notin B)) \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge ((x \in A^c) \lor (x \in B^c)) \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge (x \in A^c \cup B^c) \leftrightarrow x \in A^c \cup B^c$$

Comment: Thomas
For the sentence $4$, doesn't $\leftrightarrow$ stand?
$$$$
So, isn't it like that?
$$$$
$$x \in (A \cup B)^c \leftrightarrow x \in U \setminus A \cup B \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \notin A \cup B \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \notin A \wedge x \notin B \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \in A^c \wedge x \in B^c \leftrightarrow x \in U \wedge x \in A^c \cap B^c \leftrightarrow x \in A^c \cap B^c$$